# Keeping state of a view constant in Recyclerview after calling notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: java, android

I have a recycler adapter which has 3 itemviewtypes. No.1 type of view has an initial animation to show the view which I've written under the holder instance check in the `OnBindView` . it works fine. but when there is any change in the other view types, `notifydatasetchanged()` is called and the adapter is set again which makes the animation start again.
i tried putting a flag for the animation where it would only animate the first time. is there a smarter way to do this?

```
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {

mSharedPreferencesManager.setVersionNewFeatureCheck(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

    Logger.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder, " + viewType);

    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.converation_header_row, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
    } else if(viewType == TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_new_feature_notification, parent, false);
        return new FeatureNotificationViewHolder(v);
    }
        else{
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.conversation_row, parent, false);
        return new ConversationRowViewHolder(v);
    }
}
```

f (holder instanceof FeatureNotificationViewHolder) {
                final FeatureNotificationViewHolder featureNotificationViewHolder = (FeatureNotificationViewHolder) holder;

```
                featureNotificationViewHolder.chatNewFeatureNotif.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {

                        final int height = featureNotificationViewHolder.chatNewFeatureNotif.getMeasuredHeight();
                        featureNotificationViewHolder.chatNewFeatureNotif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        featureNotificationViewHolder.chatNewFeatureNotif.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        mOverflowAnimations.showView(featureNotificationViewHolder.chatNewFeatureNotif, height, 6);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.notifyDataSetChanged()` will notify all of your items inside the RecyclerView, if you don't want everything to reset consider using `.notifyItemChanged(int position)` method on your adapter instance. You'll need to know exactly the index/position of the item to be notified.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, on stackoverflow, if you like the answer you upvote it, and if the answer is correct you mark it as correct with the 'tick' on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged`, you should use `notifyItemChanged` to only change the item that needs to be changed, and not the whole adapter or data set.

This won't lead to the unnecessary animation because you're only changing a specific item. This is also much faster and takes up less processing and rendering power.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)).